# Access folder from desktop to MATLAB online through code

Tags: matlab, file-upload

I am not able to access folder from Downloads folder to MATLAB online version and even if I make folder of images in MATLAB online, even then it is not accessing.

I have 20 images in my folder and want to make all of them read in a variable (struct variable with fields) in MATLAB online compiler

Actually I have a folder of images in Downloads folder and want to access it in MATLAB online version, but not able to do it. I tried:

images=dir('C:\Users..........\im_patching\data_10pair')

By using breakpoints, it is seen that it is not storing any name and description of images.
It is giving : 0*1 empty struct array with fields name, folder, date, bytes, isdir, datenum

and Secondly, if I make the folder inside the MATLAB online version only and access it like

eg. Path to the images in matlab online compiler is
/MATLAB Drive/2017_CNN/patching/data_10pair/a.jpg.... (all 20 images)

now to access all the images a.jpg, b.jpg......
the MATLAB code line is

```
images = /2017_CNN/patching/data_10pair
```

after applying breakpoints it gives : 1*29 char

I want to make the "images" variable read all the names of images with the fields

My folder has 20 images.

Kindly help, I am new to MATLAB.

Comment: There's a documentation page on this, you have to upload them, your browser does not have programmatic read access of your C drive so `dir('C:\...')` is not going to work https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/access-files-in-matlab-online.html. The "secondly" part of your question implies you tried this, but you've not given us a [mcve] to make it clear what you're actually trying

Comment: @Wolfie, now i have updated my question, please see to it

Comment: You've used `dir` on a local directory which MATLAB online can't see, but then you've forgotten to use `dir` on the directory which it can see... You need `images = dir( '/2017_CNN/patching/data_10pair');`, otherwise you're just defining it as a char

Comment: Yes, I have tried it but still it is storing 0*1 empty struct array with fields name, folder, date, bytes, isdir, datenum

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/736732-how-to-specify-a-path-to-a-file-in-matlab-drive-when-using-matlab-online - `fullfile(matlabdrive, ...)` or `MATLAB Online is Linux based. The directory separator is / not \ .`

Comment: I have gone through this 
>> help fullfile
 fullfile Build full file name from parts.
    F = fullfile(FOLDERNAME1, FOLDERNAME2, ..., FILENAME) builds a full
    file specification F from the folders and file name specified.

It still requires file name i.e name of the image, whereas in my case I want to specify only folder name and the name of images will be stored in variable by itself. Even "imread" also needs a filename

Comment: Yes i got it, i was giving that path name in which I am already working. I mean, I am working under patching folder and was providing the path from the very 1st folder. It was images=dir('data_10pair/'); This works. Thankyou @Wolfie.  It was my silly mistake

Comment: The key part of my comment and link was `matlabdrive` which I think is a keyword, you can then use it with full file. Glad you fixed it, consider adding your own answer so you can accept and close the question